# How to set attribute for id with increment option and to start increment with specific number

Tags: jquery

Here is my Html part

```
 <input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
 <input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
 <input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
 <input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
 <input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
```

My jquery

```
 $('.demo').attr('id', function (i) {
    return 'Sample_' + (i + 1);
 });
```

Now I need this "i" to start from 5 rather than 0 so my result will be starting from Sample_6, Sample_7 etc..

How can i do that???

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.demo').attr('id', function (i) {
    return 'Sample_' + (i + 5);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s4F4Z/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
 var a = 5;
 $('.demo').attr('id', function (i) {
    if(i == 0) {
        a++;
        return 'Sample_' + (a);
    }
    else
        return 'Sample_' + (i + 1);
 });
```